# Search for file that has specific string in name

Tags: windows, batch-file

i'm trying to search for file that has specific string that i definied, in name using .bat file. I found out it can probably be done with Findstr but i'm beginner in batch so i can't make proper script for this.

I have only this for now

```
@echo off
echo Select path to first folder
set /p first_path=
```

So user sets the folder for searching.

Comment: what about `dir /s /a:-d /b "*New Text*"` ?

Comment: There are many ways of performing the task you require, however, I'd be reluctant to offer one of them without knowing what exactly you intend to do, once the file has been located, _if indeed, it is found_. It may be better if you were to expand on the task a little, before you select the most appropriate or efficient solution. _Currently however, neither of the answers provided come close to the efficiency of that in the comment above, (although I'd advise that you include the file extension too if you know it)_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dir` to list all files and pipe it to `findstr`.

```
dir | findstr string*
```

Important: use a wildcard **at the end only**. I tried using it at the beginning and it did not work - but using it at the end acts as if you used it at the beginning as well. Maybe someone else will chime in as to why this happens.

While this will not give you only the filename, it will find the filenames you're searching for.

Note: this will also search for yout string in the "date" and "time" sections of the `dir` output.

Comment: It's probably failing because you need quotes around the thing you're searching for

Comment: I tried adding quotes, and the result is the same - you might want to test your suggestions before commenting ...

Comment: The `*` in the `findstr` search string isn't a wildcard, it's a meta-character that matches *"zero or more occurrences of previous character or class"* (see `findstr /?`)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
dir /B /S | findstr "string"
```

The switch `/B` shows filenames completely (adding the directory name at the beginning).
The switch `/S` goes through all subdirectories (I believe this is what you are looking for?).